# How can I verify that openCV has found, and is using IPP?

Tags: c++, opencv, intel-ipp

I've set the `cmake` defines so that I should be building with IPP support enabled, but I'd like to verify that this is the case.  Since the IPP libs are statically linked I can't just check the resulting library files.